# LimeSurvey on drupal fatal error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, limesurvey

I'm currently building a site on drupal with the lime survey module. I tried configuring the synchronization between the limesurvey and my site.
I opened sites/default/settings.php, and added the lines below after the $databases['default']['default'] variable :

```
$databases['ls']['default'] = array(
'driver' => 'your_LimeSurvey_driver',
'database' => 'your_LimeSurvey_database_name',
'username' => 'your_LimeSurvey_database_username',
'password' => 'your_LimeSurvey_database_user_password',
'host' => 'your_LimeSurvey_host'
'prefix' => 'lime_' [or another value]
'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci' [or another value]
);
```

as instructed. 
I first encountered this error( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''prefix'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\lime survey\drupal-7.24\sites\default\settings.php on line 235 ) and solved it by taking the '[or another value]' out of the code.

I'm now facing these errors (http://postimg.org/image/b6ynerdr1/) (http://postimg.org/image/io7utz3a5/) and i have run out of ideas. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"your_LimeSurvey_driver" shouldn't be a literal value. You should change this to either 'mysql', 'pgsql' or 'sqlite' depending on the type of database you are using. It will probably be 'mysql'.

Similarly you should change 'your_LimeSurvey_database_name' etc to be actual names, usernames and passwords for the database, and 'your_LimeSurvey_host' should be the host the database is running on - likely to be 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' depending on your setup.